# How to consider defining a functional component inside a class component and outside the class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Considering the following three places of defining a functional component in React -

1. Inside a class (outside the render method)
2. Inside a class (inside the render method)
3. Outside the class

In the sample code below, `funcComponent1`, `funcComponent2` and `funcComponent3` are defined in the three different locations. How do I consider when to define a functional component in any of these 3 places?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const FuncComponent1 = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>{props.name}</p>
  )
}

class TestComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "JavaScript"
    }
  }


  FuncComponent2 = (text) => {
    return (
      <p>{text}, {this.state.name}</p>
    )
  }


  render(){

    const FuncComponent3 = (props) => {
      return (
        <p>{props.text}, {this.state.name}</p>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <FuncComponent1 name={'Abrar'} text={'Hello World'}/>
        <FuncComponent3 text={"HEllo World"}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: Why are you not using the functional component like a regular component? Consider using jsx, not a function call.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Updated with JSX components but I could not make the `FuncComponent2` work inside render().

Comment: Also there’s no need to wrap string props in curly braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must avoid using `functional component inside of render` since they will be recreated on every render.

As far as using `functions that return JSX inside Class component` but outside render` is considered, you can do that when you want to make use of the state or props of the class in order to render JSX content but that which is very specific to the particular class

A `functional component outside of React component` is most advantageous when the same component can be used at multiple places and hence it makes sense to pass props to it and render it.

Comment: Got it. So, outside class is the best choice unless I would want the functional component to not be reused rather particularly used for that component only.